# How do I iterate through a pandas dataframe and access a lagging or leading row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'date': ['2020-12-05', '2020-12-06', '2020-12-07'],
    'day': ['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday'],
    'score': [2, 3, 0]
    }
)
df
```

[image: df1]

In the DataFrame above, I want to update the score on Monday if the scores on the weekend were  non-zero values. For the DataFrame above, Monday's score would be 2.5. But it should work for other, longer DataFrames as well.

I know I can use the following:

```
df.score.loc[(df.day == 'Monday') & (df.score != 0) & (df.score.shift(1) != 0) & (df.score.shift(2) != 0)] = (df.score + df.score.shift(1)+df.score.shift(2))/3
df.score.loc[(df.day == 'Monday') & (df.score != 0) & (df.score.shift(1) != 0) & (df.score.shift(2) == 0)] = (df.score + df.score.shift(1))/2
df.score.loc[(df.day == 'Monday') & (df.score != 0) & (df.score.shift(1) == 0) & (df.score.shift(2) != 0)] = (df.score + df.score.shift(2))/2
df.score.loc[(df.day == 'Monday') & (df.score == 0) & (df.score.shift(1) != 0) & (df.score.shift(2) != 0)] = (df.score.shift(1) + df.score.shift(2))/2
df.score.loc[(df.day == 'Monday') & (df.score == 0) & (df.score.shift(1) != 0) & (df.score.shift(2) == 0)] = df.score.shift(1)
df.score.loc[(df.day == 'Monday') & (df.score == 0) & (df.score.shift(1) == 0) & (df.score.shift(2) != 0)] = df.score.shift(2)
```

but this is too lengthy. I think I need to iterate through the DataFrame, something like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if row.day == 'Monday':

        non_zeros = []
    
        if row.score != 0:
            non_zeros.append(row.score)
        if row.score.shift(1) != 0:
            non_zeros.append(row.score.shift(1))
        if row.score.shift(2) != 0:
            non_zeros.append(row.score.shift(2))
            
        mon_score = sum(non_zeros)/len(non_zeros)
        df.at[index, 'score'] = mon_score
```

The code above doesn't work because I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

So, it seems that `shift()` isn't correct.

How would I access the previous row and how would I access the score in the previous row? Is there a better way than manually listing the combinations of conditions, like I've done above?

Comment: *Keep* the previous row in a variable - maybe named previous.

Comment: `I have a set of other conditions ` - you didn't state what the other conditions are.

Comment: 1. The Monday score should only be updated if the weekend scores are non-zero. 2. If the Monday score is non-zero, it should be averaged with the weekend score, assuming they, also, are non-zero.

Comment: Can you state in words how Monday's score is to be updated? What are the *rules*?  Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I updated my question to include all the conditions.

Comment: You still haven't stated in words, in the question, exactly how Monday's score is to be updated. What if one or both of the weekend scores are also zero? Do we go all the way back to the last zero entry, and take the cumulative average? or else what? (is there a limit how far back we need to go, e.g. 7 days?) Also, please post a sample dataframe with say length 20, with random-seeded data, to make this reproducible. Otherwise the answer isn't well-defined.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher Consider checking the answers and if it solves your problem, upvote/accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

> How would I access the previous row

Keep the previous row in a variable - you actually want to *see* the previous two rows.

```
rows = df.iterrows()
index,minus2 = next(rows)
index,minus1 = next(rows)
for index, current in rows:
    if current.day == 'Monday':
        print(f'Saturday:{minus2.date}, Sunday:{minus2.date}, Monday:{current.date}')
        print(f'Sat score:{minus2.score}, Sun score:{minus2.score}, Mon score:{current.score}')
        print('*********')

    minus2,minus1 = minus1,current
```

---

Here is another way to do it.

Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()

dates = pd.date_range("2020-12-04", periods=60, freq="D")
days = dates.day_name()
score = rng.choice([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], size=60)
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "day": days, "score": score})

print(df.head(10))
```

Groupby weekend/weekday; if there is a score on the weekend; calculate the new Monday score; use the group's Monday index to assign a new value to the DataFrame.

```
weekends = df.day.str.contains(r"Saturday|Sunday|Monday")
days_of_interest = df[weekends]

gb = df.groupby((days_of_interest.day == "Saturday").cumsum())
for k, g in gb:
    if (g.iloc[:2].score != 0).any():
        monday = (g.iloc[-1]).name
        new_score = g.score.mean()
        # print(new_score))
        df.loc[monday, "score"] = new_score
        # print(g)
print(df)
```

It assumes the data does not *break/stop/start* on a Saturday,Sunday,Monday boundary - necessary assumption because it uses .iloc slicing/indexing and groups starting on `'Saturday'`.  Extra logic or alternate selection methods would be needed to accommodate the edge cases if the assumption is not correct.

I wasn't too sure on how the monday score was to be updated, looked like you were averaging over non-zero scores (`sum(non_zeros)/len(non_zeros)`) - including monday(?).  Maybe it should have been:

```
        # add average of weekend scores to monday score
        weekend_score = g.iloc[:2].score.mean()
        df.loc[monday,'score'] += weekend_score
        
        # or just the sum of all the scores?
        df.loc[monday,'score'] = g.score.sum()
```

Comment: When using `index, previous = next(rows)`, this will only provide the next value in the current dataframe, correct? My actual dataframe has many more rows so `next()` will not work, unless I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher - that needs to be done to get the first row *into* `previous Then the for loop iteration starts at row two. At the *bottom* of the for loop assign the current row to previous. You actually need to see the previous two rows - I changed that part of my answer to accommodate that. The second solution in my answer using groupby works.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'date': ['2020-12-05', '2020-12-06', '2020-12-07', '2020-12-05', '2020-12-06', '2020-12-07'],
    'day': ['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday','Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday'],
    'score': [-0.2, 0, 0.0, -0.3, 0, 0.0]
    }
)
```

Based on the question, if we have to access previous rows based on row in question, we can use below

```
mondays = df['day']=='Monday'
sundays = df.score.shift(1)[mondays]
saturdays = df.score.shift(2)[mondays]
# row_mask_for_upd = mondays & sundays.astype(bool) | saturdays.astype(bool)  # if either of sundays or saturdays have to be non zero
row_mask_for_upd = mondays & sundays.astype(bool) & saturdays.astype(bool)  # if both sundays and saturdays have to be non zero
if True in set(row_mask_for_upd):
    df.loc[row_mask_for_upd, "score"] = (sundays + saturdays)/2
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Other Inputs and Outputs:

1. Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

2. Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: i get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'float'` for `mondays & saturdays & sundays` .....   how about `indices = sundays[saturdays +  sundays != 0].index; df.loc[indices,'score'] = ((saturdays+sundays)/2).loc[indices]`

Comment: @wwii I have modified the statement and commented there to explain the condition. It should work now. What you have suggested also works.

Comment: Pandas version 1.1.4 - still getting a TypeErrror for logic operations between two Series of type float or float and bool.   `saturdays.astype(bool) | sundays.astype(bool)` works for me.

Comment: ok. Then it changed in version 1. I am not getting any error in 0.25.1.
Thank you. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, this might be the solution you have been looking for. I have assumed that your dummy data might be same(no Nulls or any other randomized rows) Try following if you want to use shift().

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'date': ['2020-11-30','2020-12-05', '2020-12-06', '2020-12-07'],
    'day': ['Monday','Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday'],
    'score': [4, 2, 3, 0]
    }
)

def update(row,df1,df2):

  score_Mon = row['score']
  score_Sun = df1.iloc[row.name]['score']
  score_Sat = df2.iloc[row.name]['score']

  # Base condition if previous Saturday,Sunday values available, else put 
  # default value only
  if row['day'] == 'Monday' and not(math.isnan(score_Sun)) and 
not(math.isnan(score_Sat)):

    # Non zero condition
    if score_Mon != 0 and score_Sun > 0 and score_Sat > 0:
      row['score'] = (score_Mon + score_Sun + score_Sat)/3

    # Zero condition
    else:
      row['score'] = (score_Sun + score_Sat)/2

  return row

df = df.apply(update,axis=1,args = [df.shift(1),df.shift(2)])
df
```

[image]